# After create site collection in sharepoint, how to check whether it's ready(how long) to create subsites in it?

Tags: sharepoint-online

After creating a site collection in sharepoint by "New-SPOSite", it can't be displayed in Admin Console->Active sites immediately, so that I can't create subsite or other site content in it soon. My question is: how to judge(use which command) the new created site collection is ready for use?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal that it takes some time to create a new site collection. If you could see the new site collection in the active sites page of SharePoint Admin Center. The new created site collection is ready for use. Then you could create subsite and other site content.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do when create site collection and the site contents in Admin Center by manual. But this question comes from when I use poweshell script to do the same thing. After I use script to create site collection, then create List into it, it will fail to create List(or other site contents) becasue the site collection doesn't ready yet. I want to know which command or method can be used in script to judge the new site is ready and I can continue to create List in it.

Comment: `
New-SPOSite -Url $url -title $title -Owner $username -StorageQuota $storageQuota -NoWait -Template $template
#check whether has finished creating
do{
$finish = get-SPOSite -Limit ALL| where{$_.url -eq $url}
sleep 10
}
while($finish -eq $null)
`
my code like above which have already used Get-SPOSite to check, but it doen't work as expected. When the new site collection is still creating(not show in the active sites page of SharePoint Admin Center), Get-SPOSite can return the new site.